# Display shortcode based on user meta

Tags: php, functions, shortcode, user-meta

I have been working on a project where I want to display a shortcode based on the user meta data. I have added a user meta while creating a new user. The default value of the user meta is set to false. Now, my logic is to check whether the user meta is 'false' or not at the time of login. I will be displaying the shortcode if the value is 'false' and after that again updating the user meta to 'true'. But, this is not working. The new created user when logs in, is not able to see any shortcode.
Can find my mistake?

**This code adds user meta for all the newly created users**

```
add_filter( 'insert_user_meta', 'new_user_meta', 20, 3);
function new_user_meta( $meta, $user, $update ) 
{
    if ( $update )
        return $meta;

    $meta['GDPR_TERMS_READ'] = false;
    return $meta;
}
```

**This piece of code checks whether the user meta is false or not to Display the shortcode**

```
add_action( 'init', 'gdpr_flag' );
function gdpr_flag() {
  $current_user = get_current_user_id();
  if ( ! $current_user ) {
    // user not logged in
    return;
  }
  if ( get_user_meta( $current_user, 'GDPR_TERMS_READ', true ) ) {
    // user meta set already
    return;
  }
  // render some html
  echo do_shortcode( '[wpterms id="2230"]' );
  // update user meta
  updateHasReadFlag( $current_user );  
}

function updateHasReadFlag($user) {
  // I added support for using this function either with user ID or user object
  if ( $user && is_int( $user ) ) {
    $user_id = $user;
  } else if ( ! empty( $user->ID ) ) {
    $user_id = $user->ID;
  } else {
    return;
  }
  return update_user_meta( $user_id, 'GDPR_TERMS_READ', true );
}
```

**This is the code generated for pop up from the plugin**

```
<div id="tlight" class="tbrightcontent">
    <div class="termspopupcontainer">
                <h3 class="termstitle">GDPR</h3>

        <div class="termscontentwrapper">
            <p>This is a GDPR pop up.</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<form><input name="accept" type="checkbox" value="Gdpr">I accept the GDPR</form>
        </div>


        <form method="post">
                        <div class="tthebutton">
                <input class="termsagree" name="wptp_agree" type="submit" value="Accept">
                <input class="termsdecline" type="button" onclick="window.location.replace('https://google.com')" value="I Do Not Agree">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're retrieving a single value, so the third parameter should be `true` here: `get_user_meta($user->ID, 'HAS_READ', false)`. But the `wp_authenticate` hook is called before the authentication cookies are set, so you shouldn't be echoing anything from your hook callback.

Comment: sorry i did not get you. you mean to say that    echo do_shortcode( "[wpterms id=2230]" );  wont work here. I have updated my code, please have a look.

Comment: will add_action('wp_login', 'gdprFlag'); work instead of wp_authentiate?

Comment: Can you show a sample output of the shortcode - what's the output or the expected output of `[wpterms id="2230"]` ? "*Little information about my shortcode is that, its a pop up.*" - are you trying to show a popup once per login/user session? I.e. It's shown each time after the user logs in?

Comment: Yes Sally, you are right. The shortcode is just a simple pop up with a button “Accept”. In reality, I will calling updateHasReadFlag() from the onClick of the “Accept” button. So that once the user accepts the the GDPR popup, he will never be able to see the pop up again. Hope I have explained correctly.

Comment: Ok, but what's the workflow? 1) User logs in (via `wp-login.php` ?). 2) User sees the popup. 3) User clicks the "Accept" button. Is that so? Do you use JS to make the popup appears?

Comment: When the user gets created he/she will meta data (GDPR_HAS_READ) = false. Now when the user logs in , I am checking whether the GDPR_HAS_READ = false. If this is true then I am displaying the pop up using the Shortcode. Now when the users clicks on ACCEPT. I will be calling updateHasRead() to update GDPR_HAS_READ = true so that he will not see the pop up again. I think the shortcode handles the JS part. Is my understanding right?

Comment: Can you just show a sample output of the shortcode, even if it's a simple popup? Just add the generated output/code to your question, or post it on Pastebin.

Comment: @Subham Could you share your code for the shortcode? And if the user meta for reading the gdpr notice should be updated after the user clicks a button, then  `updateHasReadFlag()` should be removed from the `gdpr_flag` action. With the current setup the user meta gets updated regardless whether the user clicks Accept button or not.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question with the code for the pop up which has been generated by the plugin.

Comment: @AnttiKoskinen Yes, the `updateHasReadFlag()` will be called from onClick of the Agree button. Just for demonstration I have added in the `gdpr_flag()`

Comment: @Subham Thank you for the additional information. Is `[wpterms id="2230"]` just a placeholder in the code you've posted or the real shortcode? Are there any `if` statements in your shortcode function that might block the html rendering? What if you replace `echo do_shortcode()` with `?><!-- the popup html --><?`. Is the popup showing then?

Comment: @AnttiKoskinen The pop up plugin what I am using, displays pop ups based on cookies. When I am clearing the cache in my browser then the pop up is getting displayed. How can I make the short code independent on cookies?

Comment: @Subham, I think you should ask that cookie thing as a new, separate, question so that other community members can see it and provide their answers, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the shortcode you're using renders some html. If this is the case, then you could consider hooking your function to some later action, maybe one in your theme, so that the shortcode content gets rendered along with all the other html. You could even consider using `wp_footer`, if such late hook is ok.

You could then maybe write your functions something like this,

```
add_action( 'some_theme_hook', 'gdpr_flag' );

function gdpr_flag() {
  $current_user = get_current_user_id();
  if ( ! $current_user ) {
    // user not logged in
    return;
  }
  if ( get_user_meta( $current_user, 'HAS_READ', true ) ) {
    // user meta set already
    return;
  }
  // render some html
  echo do_shortcode( "[wpterms id=2230]" );
  // update user meta
  updateHasReadFlag( $current_user );  
}

function updateHasReadFlag($user) {
  // I added support for using this function either with user ID or user object
  if ( $user && is_int( $user ) ) {
    $user_id = $user
  } else if ( ! empty( $user->ID ) ) {
    $user_id = $user->ID;
  } else {
    return;
  }
  return update_user_meta( $user_id, 'HAS_READ', true );
}
```

---

*P.S. You might want to consider renaming the meta key, as "HAS_READ" doesn't tell much about what the meta data is for. Especially if some other developer happens to have a look at your code or works with the user meta some time later. Perhaps using something like "gdpr_term_read" could be more explicit.*

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your interest. I have hooked my function to wp_footer but somehow the shortcode is not getting rendered. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: @Subham, update your question with the code you've attempted in the `wp_footer` hook. And the theme's `footer.php` does call `wp_footer()` like [this](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/twentynineteen/1.4/footer.php#L54), right?

Comment: I have hooked it to the 'init' hook. My theme calls 'init' and moreover I can see that the user meta is getting inserted and updated for a new user. All of the code is running fine except the main part(displaying the shortcode). Little information about my shortcode is that, its a pop up.

Comment: @Subham, if your theme does not call `wp_footer()`, add `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` to `footer.php`, before `</body>`. Secondly, are you sure the popup HTML is not in the page source? Maybe the popup is just being visually hidden via CSS. Check also the console for errors, including missing resources like a JS file/script.

Comment: @SallyCJ I am facing issue while calling the `updateHasReadFlag()` from the click of Agree button using AJAX. Can demonstrate or share any link where I can get an idea. Thank you.

Comment: @Subham, I suppose the popup is now showing, and if so, I suggest you to accept the answer, and for the AJAX part, see [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/24308). And if you got stuck, you can post a new question.